# How to get Ruby MySQL returning PHP like DB SELECT result

Tags: mysql, ruby, prepared-statement

So I use the PDO for a DB connection like this:

```
$this->dsn[$key] = array('mysql:host=' . $creds['SRVR'] . ';dbname=' . $db, $creds['USER'], $creds['PWD']);
$this->db[$key] = new PDO($this->dsn[$key]);
```

Using PDO I can then execute a MySQL SELECT using something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute($id);
$result = $st->fetchAll();
```

The $result variable will then return an array of arrays where each row is given a incremental key - the first row having the array key 0.  And then that data will have an array the DB data like this:

```
$result (array(2)
  [0]=>[0=>1, "id"=>1, 1=>"stuff", "field1"=>"stuff", 2=>"more stuff", "field2"=>"more stuff" ...],
  [1]=>[0=>2, "id"=>2, 1=>"yet more stuff", "field1"=>"yet more stuff", 2=>"even more stuff", "field2"=>"even more stuff"]);
```

In this example the DB table's field names would be id, field1 and field2.  And the result allows you to spin through the array of data rows and then access the data using either a index (0, 1, 2) or the field name ("id", "field1", "field2").  Most of the time I prefer to access the data via the field names but access via both means is useful.

So I'm learning the ruby-mysql gem right now and I can retrieve the data from the DB.  However, I cannot get the field names.  I could probably extract it from the SQL statement given but that requires a fair bit of coding for error trapping and only works so long as I'm not using SELECT * FROM ... as my SELECT statement.

So I'm using a table full of State names and their abbreviations for my testing.  When I use "SELECT State, Abbr FROM states" with the following code

```
st = @db.prepare(sql)
if empty(where)
  st.execute()
else
  st.execute(where)
end

rows = []
while row = st.fetch do
  rows << row
end
st.close

return rows
```

I get a result like this:

```
[["Alabama", "AL"], ["Alaska", "AK"], ...]
```

And I'm wanting a result like this:

```
[[0=>"Alabama", "State"=>"Alabama", 1=>"AL", "Abbr"=>"AL"], ...]
```

I'm guessing I don't have the way inspect would display it quite right but I'm hoping you get the idea by now.

Anyway to do this?  I've seen some reference to doing this type of thing but it appears to require the DBI module.  I guess that isn't the end of the world but is that the only way?  Or can I do it with ruby-mysql alone?

I've been digging into all the methods I can find without success.  Hopefully you guys can help.

Thanks
Gabe

Answer (score 1):

You can do this yourself without too much effort:

```
expanded_rows = rows.map do |r|
    { 0 => r[0], 'State' => r[0], 1 => r[1], 'Abbr' => r[1] }
end
```

Or a more general approach that you could wrap up in a method:

```
columns = ['State', 'Abbr']
expanded_rows = rows.map do |r|
    0.upto(names.length - 1).each_with_object({}) do |i, h|
        h[names[i]] = h[i] = r[i]
    end
end
```

So you could collect up the `rows` as you are now and then pump that array of arrays through something like what's above and you should get the sort of data structure you're looking for out the other side.

There are other methods on the `row` you get from `st.fetch` as well:

> http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/Mysql/Result

But you'll have to experiment a little to see what exactly they return as the documentation is, um, a little thin.

You should be able to get the column names out of `row` or `st`:

> http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/Mysql/Stmt

but again, you'll have to experiment to figure out the API. Sorry, I don't have anything set up to play around with the MySQL API that you're using so I can't be more specific.

Comment: I actually don't have anything against a layer.  My main issue is this - I started with PHP a few years back.  And out of habit from other languages - writing code others said couldn't be written to automate engineering tasks - I created several useful classes in PHP.  Now I am simply trying to recreate those a few of the most useful classes in Ruby so that my coding in Ruby can closely resemble my code in PHP.  A language that I'm comfortable with and frankly has better documentation and error reporting (IMHO).

Comment: Sorry the above was meant for the answer from pguaridario.

Comment: My main problem right now isn't getting the fetched data but rather getting what the column field names are.  What you are suggesting in your first instance requires specific code for each and every query I code up which largely defeats the purpose.  What I need to find is a method that will let me extract the column field names from the SELECT result.  Then I could build my own wrapper around the result.

Comment: @gabe: Your Ruby should look like Ruby though, not PHP; I regularly use Ruby, Perl, JavaScript, C, and three flavors of SQL so I hear you on the multi-language issue but when in Rome... And, yes, the documentation at php.net is way better than anything in the Ruby or Rails world and that's a fact (not an opinion :)

Comment: @gabe: You'll have to play with the methods in Result and Stmt, there should be something in there that will tell you the column names. You can use the documentation (ha ha) as a list of methods to try and `puts x.inspect` for some `x` to see what they give you.

Comment: Yeah I spent hours doing that already before asking the question here without any luck.

Comment: What does `row.fetch_hash` or `row.fetch_hash(true)` do? Anything of interest in `st.result_metadata`?

Comment: result_metadata returns garbage like #<Mysql::Stmt:0xb7444e4c>
fetch_hash returns an error stating: "undefined method 'fetch_hash' for ["Alabama", "AL"]:Array (NoMethodError)" whether I use fetch_hash or fetch_hash(true).

Answer (score 0):

I realize that php programmers are all cowboys who think using a db layer is cheating, but you should really consider activerecord.

Comment: FYI: Using a db layer that can handle multiple db formats with all sorts of extra stuff comes with additional overhead.  If you intend to only run 1 instance of your code then yes the overhead is not worth worrying about.  However, if you intend to run dozens of instances then the overhead can be an issue.  Possibly an issue solved by multi-threading but not always solved by that.  Sometimes there are reasons for minimizing overhead and thus minimizing the number of unnecessary classes you include via require statements.

Comment: Ah but sacrificing a bit of overhead for convenience is the ruby way.

Comment: Yeah, I've just been working on parallel/distributed applications where any given server might be running dozens (say, close to 100) instances simultaneously.  I've learned the head way the convenience at this level a concurrent instances can bring down your server.  Where as clean, optimized code that actively manages memory can easily handle the load and then some.  So for my purposes... convenience in code means having to buy and maintain a lot more machines.

Comment: In that case why would you switch from php to ruby?

Comment: I need to drive a web browser automatically for testing purposes.  PHP doesn't have anything like that as far as I know.  Watir - in Ruby - allows me to drive a browser just like I would if I were sitting in front of it.  But I still keep all my test case data in a DB.  So I wanted to create a class in Ruby to mimic my PHP class that gives me easy DB access.  I've been using that PHP class for 18 months or so and I want the Ruby class to return the results in a nearly identical manner so my code can be copied from one language to the other with minimal rewrite.

Comment: @gabe - php has phpunit with selenium server integration. When I write php, I write my unit tests with phpunit and then write my functional tests subclassing the seleniumtestcase class that comes with phpunit. If you want to get real fancy, you can use [jenkins](http://jenkins-php.org/) and automate the whole process.

Comment: @AndrewPK phpunit certainly has potential. This whole thing ahs been back burnered while I rewrite my PHP tools (to incorp 2+ years of exp and Namespaces). I've written plenty of distributed task managers using beanstalk and I'm currently exploring gearman for other reasons. So automating the browser tasks will likely remain a custom bit of PHP. I did however really like the idea that jenkins could check on the result of a cron job. Crons not correctly running has been a PITA for some time. Thanks again.